# How to edit the Finder context menu when no file or folder is clicked

Tags: terminal, finder, automator, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I want to create shortcuts like "Copy path of current folder" and "Open terminal in current folder" in the screenshotted context menu. I know how achieve this with Services and Automator but only for when a file or folder is right-clicked. How do I do it when a blank area is right-clicked?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked, "How do I do it when a blank area is right-clicked?", well sans the content of the *default context menu*, I believe something has to be selected to be acted upon otherwise you'll always just get the *default context menu*. That said though, you could create an **Automator** *Service* that receives no input in **Finder** and assign it a keyboard shortcut. Then using **AppleScript**, you would code it to do what you want based on the `target` *property* of the front window of **Finder**.

The following two *example* **AppleScript** *code* segments can be used in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *Service* to which a keyboard shortcut can be assigned or as an **AppleScript** *Application* created in **Script Editor** and the app dragged and dropped onto the **Toolbar** in **Finder**.

This example copies to the clipboard the POSIX path of the current folder of the front **Finder** window:

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        set the clipboard to text items 1 thru -2 of POSIX path of (target of front window as string) as string
    end tell
end try
```

This example opens **Terminal** to the current folder of the front **Finder** window:

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        set theTargetPath to text items 1 thru -2 of POSIX path of (target of front window as string) as string
    end tell
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "pushd " & theTargetPath & "; clear"
        activate
    end tell
end try
```

That said though, the only other thing I can think of would be to use **Xcode** and create a **Service** or **App Extension** to do what you're asking, if it's even doable.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and, sans the `try` *statement* as an *error handler*, does not include any other *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any appropriate *error handling* for any *example code* presented.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 apps that add an icon to the finder window which will open a terminal window in the directory displayed. The apps are '**GotoShell**' and '**ShellHere**'. I have both apps and they both seem to work equally well. GotoShell allows the user to select either Terminal or iTerm for your command line program. You can also define a script to run when the window is opened.